# Qt - How to convert Qt::Key into nativeVirtualKey

Tags: c++, qt, qkeyevent

How can I convert a `Qt::Key` (eg. `Qt::Key_At`) into `nativeVirtualKey` code outside of a `keyPressEvent()` or a `keyReleaseEvent()`?

Comment: Add some code fro what you have done and fials.

Comment: The case is simple. Inside a QKeyEvent you can get the corresponding nativeVirtualKey of pressed key with event->nativeVirtualKey()... but how I can get the corresponding nativeVirtualKey of aany Qt::Key outside of a QKeyEvent?

Comment: outside of QKeyEvent why outside? Describe more about the reason you need to handle key events outside QEvent handlers.

Comment: Add a code sample and describe where exactly you want native key handle

Comment: Even you can use a global variable and assign value to it

Comment: The [source for qxtglobalshortcut](https://github.com/mnutt/libqxt/blob/master/src/gui/qxtglobalshortcut_win.cpp) suggests you will have to create your own mapping. If there was a method that did reverse look-up, I'm sure libqxt would be using it.